# How to solve ERROR: Only Secure Origin are allowed for WEBCAM

Tags: web, localhost

I have created a simple system that use webcam to capture photo in COMP A using localhost. The problem is when I try to access the system using COMP B by typing `ip_address:port_number`, for example`192.168.1.4:80` the webcam wont work.
The ip address and port number is from COMP A.

It will show `Error:  DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed` when I access the webcam and it show nothing. Is there any way to make it run even without `https://`?

Thanks